# Reasons for: "Transaction resolves to incorrect ledger balance" in IRI (1.4.1.6)

Tags: wallet, iri-node

I'm running multiple fullnodes which are completely synced. However, some light wallet users are reporting problems and I see

`Transaction resolves to incorrect ledger balance`

in the IRI logs for those users.

What does this mean semantically? What went wrong (in terms of the root cause for this to happen)? How can we resolve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

The bundle that this transaction is part of has a value sum which is not zero which means that the bundle cannot be picked for approval by other transactions.

In other words, the bundle tries to send more (or less) IOTA to its output addresses than it tries to spend from its input addresses.

Most likely cause would be a bug in the wallet, but perhaps it helps if you can have a look at the transactions (or post the details here).

Comment: Interesting. From the wording of the error message I thought it is regarding double spends. Is there an error for double spends, too?

Comment: @Akkumulator iri will not detect double spends in any way. Double spends are fine to exist on the network, is is just thaat only one of them may confirm. The only way you can see double spends is if you ask whether they are consistent with the latest milestone (or by the fact that despite promoting it like crazy it will never confirm).

Comment: but it checks for them when selecting tips, right?

Comment: @Akkumulator yes. So you also know it is not a double spend when it gets selected as a tip.